# Как получить статус принтера?

Tags: java, принтер

Интересны такие статусы как: принтер активен, подключен, ну если есть возможность то ещё бумага осталась или нет.

таким образом получаю всех принтеров:

```
public List<String> getPrinters() {

    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintService printServices[] = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(
            flavor, pras);

    List<String> printerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (PrintService printerService : printServices) {
        printerList.add(printerService.getName());
    }

    return printerList;
}
```

а как дальше быть не совсем понимаю, в интернете в основном предлагают воспользоваться с классом `PrinterStateReasons` но пока не понимаю как это делается?

Comment: Просто интересно, что за принтер?

Comment: да любой в моем случае XPrinter (термопринтер) XP-80C

Comment: А зачем вам что то писать на java? Не ПО что ли? + как принтер выполняет java байткод, под него что, есть jvm?

Comment: извините но не совсем понял вашего вопроса...

Comment: Почему вы пишите на javа для принтера? Нельзя скачать приложение и распечатать что вам надо, как делают все? + вы уверены, что на нем запустится то, что вы написали? Или как вы запускаете на нем свои программы?

Comment: у меня уже реализован основной часть программы, остался только получить статус принтера да потому что принтер находится на другом месте (по требованию заказчика). Идея заключается в том что оператор принимает заказы нажимает на печать а на принтере печатается... все это уже сделано остался только сказать оператору что если принтер отключен то соответствующее сообщение о том что принтер отключен или ещё что то...